# How to color dc js scatter plot according to the column value

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to get a scatter plot using dc.js. From my csv data file, following scatter plot attributes are assigned: size of bubble --> No. of sessions, xaxis --> Average time on page, yaxis --> Bounce rate, number of bubbles  --> Sources
I also want the colors of bubbles to be decided using another column from the csv file.
Colors --> source category. (Source category is the category of the sources. SO there are 8 categories currently in my data file and therefore i need 8 colors.

Also i need the legends for those 8 colors.

Which dc.js function am i suppose to use to achieve the same?

Comment: Have you looked at the [scatter-series example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/scatter-series.html)?

Comment: I have checked it and have implemented the colors accordongly but i want legens according to those colors and those legens should be filterable. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes.  ;-)  The functionality is not built in, however - you'd have to add onClick behavior to the legend in a renderlet.

Comment: That sounds good. But before this, how to get the legend according to the coloraccessor value?

Comment: Yes. The legend should use the coloraccessor.  Does it not?  It looks like you could also directly use the scatter plot with the legend, without the series part.  One or the other should work.

Comment: The legends seems to not use the colorAccessor. Can you explain a bit on the second option?