# add legend to dc.js scatterplot

Tags: d3.js, legend, scatter-plot, dc.js

Somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060337/how-to-color-dc-js-scatter-plot-according-to-the-column-value).

I would like to add a legend to a scatterplot using dc.js, ideally with the possibility of highlighting points based on hover/click of the corresponding legend. The [source code](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/scatter-plot.js.html) seems to indicate that `color` is "legendable" for scatterplots, but I cannot find any examples where this is done.

Running the code below in the browser triggers an error:

> `tmp.html:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
>       at Object.myChart.dimension.group.colorAccessor.d (tmp.html:26)
>       at Object._chart.getColor (color-mixin.js:149)
>       at Object._chart.legendables (scatter-plot.js:360)
>       at Object._legend.render (legend.js:45)
>       at Object._chart.render (base-mixin.js:703)
>       at Object.dc.renderAll (core.js:230)
>       at tmp.html:33`

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dc.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter2/1.4.6/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.0.9/dc.js"></script>
</head><body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

dc.config.defaultColors(d3.schemeCategory10);
var myChart = dc.scatterPlot("#chart");

let input = [{x:0,y:0,c:1}, {x:1,y:1,c:0},{x:0.5,y:0.5,c:2}];
(function(data) {

    var ndx = crossfilter(input),
        dims = ndx.dimension( d => [+d.x,+d.y,+d.c]),
        grp = dims.group();

    myChart
        .dimension(dims)
        .group(grp)
        .colorAccessor(d=> +d.key[2])
        .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(d3.extent(input, d => +d.x))))
        .valueAccessor(d => +d.key[1])
        .brushOn(false)
        .legend(dc.legend().x(750).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5));
})(input);

dc.renderAll();
</script></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately it is a bug that was reported a long time ago, but has never been fixed. The scatter plot is calling `_chart.getColor()` with no arguments.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1138#issuecomment-217861014

Even if it's fixed, it's only returning one legendable, so I think it will only work for the scatter-series case. If you want to display legend items for each color in your chart, you'll have to generate that data yourself:

```
myChart.legendables = function () {
    var byColor = {};
    myChart.group().all().forEach(function(d) {
        var color = myChart.colors()(myChart.colorAccessor()(d));
        byColor[color] = {
            chart: myChart,
            name: 'color ' + myChart.colorAccessor()(d),
            color: color
        };
    })
    return Object.values(byColor);
};
```

Maybe the chart should do something this automatically. One complication is that there currently aren't any names defined for colors - here I just pasted `'color '` with the value returned by the color accessor, but you presumably have better names in your actual data set.

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/by1g7kw2/33/).

Comment: Your workaround seems to create a legend with a color (black) without a label, and not part of the data, and hovering this fades all the existing data out. How would I go from this to having a legend with labels and colors corresponding to the data?

Comment: Whoops, I only got as far as fixing the crash.  I'll try to take another look at this today.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer, generating a legend item for each color.